# Merging files based on dates

Tags: linux, bash, shell

In the bash script, I am trying to merge files weekly data into a fiscal year file, where a FY starts in JUNE of every year and ends by MAY of every year. Weekly files are suffixed with weekend dates in YYYYMMDD format. I am trying to put together a logic that creates FY files.

**Weekly files:**

- blahblahblah_20191207.txt
- blahblahblah_20191214.txt
- blahblahblah_20191221.txt

**FY Files:**

- FY2019.txt includes data from June 2018 to MAY 2019
- FY2020.txt includes data from June 2019 to MAY 2020

**Exception:**

- blahblahblah_20190630.txt may contain few days data pertaining to FY19 and FY10

**Question:**
How do I put a logic together in bash script for this?
I tried this but doesn’t seem to work…

```
newfymonth="06"
fiscal_file="Not_Defined"
current_year=`(date +"%Y")`
currentyearminusone=`echo "$(($current_year - 1))"`
currentyearplusone=`echo "$(($current_year + 1))"`
if [ "$filemonth" -ge "$newfymonth" ] && [ "$fileyear" -eq "$current_year" ]; then
            fyfileyear=`echo "$(($fileyear + 1))"` 
            fiscal_file="FY"$fileyear".txt"
        elif [ "$filemonth" -lt "$newfymonth" ] && [ "$fileyear" -eq "$current_year" ]; then
            fyfileyear=`echo "$(($fileyear))"` 
            fiscal_file="FY"$fileyear".txt"
        elif [ "$filemonth" -ge "$newfymonth" ] && [ "$fileyear" -eq "$currentyearminusone" ]; then
            fyfileyear=`echo "$(($fileyear + 1))"`
            fiscal_file="FY"$fileyear".txt" 
        elif [ "$filemonth" -lt "$newfymonth" ] && [ "$fileyear" -eq "$currentyearplusone" ]; then
            fyfileyear=`echo "$(($fileyear))"` 
            fiscal_file="FY"$fileyear".txt" 
fi
```

**Additional Information: File structure**

Mar =March. First 3 letters of a month. Data is something like this...

```
"ASAP","Castaway","Broadway","Ju1-9-2019","Recyle","NYNY","Pausing","Material","Nature",,55.5640,,0.3350,-10.9250,1.7450,,,,,,,1.3500,,,3.1750,21.5000
"ASAP","Castaway","Broadway","Aug-9-2019","Recyle","NYNY","Pausing","Material","Nature",,55.5640,,0.3350,-10.9250,1.7450,,,,,,,1.3500,,,3.1750,21.5000 
"ASAP","Castaway","Broadway","Sep-9-2019","Recyle","NYNY","Pausing","Material","Nature",,55.5640,,0.3350,-10.9250,1.7450,,,,,,,1.3500,,,3.1750,21.5000
```

Comment: Does the content of the files contain the date? Can't you concatenate all the files and then filter the lines that are connected to a given year? `may contain few days data pertaining to FY19 and FY10` - how to differentiate them?

Comment: Yes it contains date in one of a column in a text form. But code wise say I concatenated all of them into a single file. How will the code look like to split rows based on date in different FY files?

Comment: That depends on what is the format of the date in the column. It would be a one-line script in `awk`. Like `awk -vf=$(date --date=2019 +%s) -vt=$(date --date=2020 +%s) 'f <= $1 && $1 < t'`

Comment: Please post some example lines of the content of the files. In which column is the date stored? How are columns separated? The `Mar` part is in what language? Posting sample like 10 lines of the files would clear such questions. There are really many, many similar questions and answers using `awk` scripts to extract parts of the file using a timestamp.

Comment: Please edit your question and post additional information in the question.

Comment: indent the relevant part, highlight then using your mouse and use `Ctrl+k`

Comment: New user, excuse me. I did the indentation part.

Answer (score 0):

I mean this can be solved based on how you format your file... for example if it's something like `YYMMDD-log.txt` you can just check each file that has the simply check the date if the same date as the current log then append the data to latest one.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming:

- The field values do not include comma characters (at least the first three fields prior to
    the date field).
- The day of the month is represented as "6", not "06" in case the number is less than 10.
- The name of the month is represented in upper camel case of three characters.

Then how about:

```
declare -A m2n=([Jan]=1 [Feb]=2 [Mar]=3 [Apr]=4 [May]=5 [Jun]=6
        [Jul]=7 [Aug]=8 [Sep]=9 [Oct]=10 [Nov]=11 [Dec]=12)
                                                        # table of month name
for f in *.txt; do
    [[ $f =~ .*[[:digit:]]{8]\.txt ]] || continue       # skip other files
    while IFS= read -r line; do
        IFS="," read j0 j1 j2 date j3 <<< "$line"       # extract the date field
        IFS="-" read m d y <<< "${date//\"/}"           # split into mon, day, year
        fy=$y                                           # fiscal year
        mn=${m2n[$m]}                                   # monname to number
        (( mn >= 6)) && (( fy++ ))                      # adjust fiscal year
        printf "%04d,%04d%02d%02d,%s\n" "$fy" "$y" "$mn" "$d" "$line"
                                                        # prepend fiscal year and canonicalized date for sorting and determining the output fi
le
    done < "$f"
done | sort | while IFS="," read -r fy date rest; do
    file="FY${fy}.txt"                                  # output filename
    echo "$rest" >> "$file"
done
```

- It first merges all lines as advised by KamilCuk.
- While merging the lines, it prepends the fiscal year and the canonicalized date to the line in order to sort the lines later.
- In the following `while` loop it determines the destination filename.